# Why is my document moving out of alignment after the first page

Tags: vertical-alignment

I already tried using `\noindent` but this error actually keeps happening on every other page.

The problem can be seen below when observing the difference in alignment of the (4) and the (5)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: Which `\documentclass` are you using?

Answer (score 3):

This is because LaTeX is formatting your document so that when the pages are printed double-sided, it can be bound as a book. The default is to have different margins on the inner edge (next to the spine) and the outer edge.

Try adding `\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1]{geometry}` to your preamble. The `geometry` package is the preferred way to fiddle with page margins these days. The `hmarginratio=1:1` option makes the horizontal margins on even and odd pages the same.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I also just realized I could use this \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{5mm} \setlength{\evensidemargin}{5mm}

Comment: Indeed. Yet another option is to use `\documentclass[oneside]{...}`, as explained in [this lovely blog post](http://texblog.org/2013/02/13/latex-documentclass-options-illustrated/#doublesided). This should give you symmetric margins, and will also put your page numbers in the same place on every page.